# JavaScript Error because of rendered velocity line-break

Tags: javascript, velocity, line-breaks, liferay-velocity, liferay-aui

I use JavaScript-code in a velocity-template and it's not working!

I read content with this template and want to set this to a js-variable, but there are line-breaks in the content and I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

In the rendered code there you see the error:

```
var exampleText = 'This is the first line

and this is the second line.';
```

In the original code it is written this way:

```
    var exampleText = '$question.answer.data';
var regularPanels = new A.Panel( { 
    bodyContent: exampleText, 
    collapsible: true, 
    collapsed: true,
    headerContent: '$question.data' } ) .render('#regularPanels$counter$reserved-article-id.data$randomNamespace');  

});
```

Is there a possibility to ignore the linebreak for the js-compilation, but still show it on the complete rendered page?

---

Okay, I solved it with the help of the [EscapeTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic/EscapeTool.html) by Velocity.

Combined with the answer from emiliocai it's the following code which works fine:

```
<div id="example-text" style="display:none;">
   <p>$escapeTool.java($question.answer.data).replace("\n","<br />")</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

AUI().ready('aui-panel', function(A) { 

var exampleText = document.getElementById('example-text').innerHTML;
var regularPanels = new A.Panel( { 
    bodyContent: exampleText, 
    collapsible: true, 
    collapsed: true,
    headerContent: '$question.data' } ) .render('#regularPanels$counter$reserved-article-id.data$randomNamespace');  

});

</script>
```

It might be, that it would work without the hidden `<div>`-Tag, but I haven't tested it yet.

So also possible would be:

```
var exampleText = '$escapeTool.java($question.answer.data).replace("\n","<br />")';
```

---

Tested it -> works!

Comment: not sure if I understand but can't you use <br> or \n instead of newlines?

Comment: Thats the problem. I would like so, but these newlines are generated by the template. In the database the content (question.answer.data) is saved with <p></p> - tags for the new lines. That's okay, but I think they will be compiled to new lines before the content gets in the script-function. I tried to catch and replace the linebreaks on many ways but can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but newlines are not acceptable in JavaScript, not sure how your template looks like but if you really cannot replace the newlines by \n or `<br>` the you can do a trick:

- In the template render the contents coming from the database into a hidden div:

  `<div id="example-text" style="display:none">$question.answer.data</div>`
- In your javascript code read the contents of the div into your variable:

  `var exampleText = document.getElementById('example-text').innerHTML;`

Comment: thanks :) I already knew that newlines aren't acceptable, but it seems that velocity doesn't know :'D there is no error anymore and the content is shown, but now all is shown in one line. Isn't there any possibility to escape or catch a linebreak?

Comment: you could try replacing the \n for `<br>` like this: `var exampleText = document.getElementById('example-text').innerHTML.replace("\n","<br>");`

Comment: I've already tried replacing, but it's still not working. It would be much easier if I would know what kind of linebreak is used by velocity, because it's neither \n nor <p> (which is stored in the database).